# Camper battery charge

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, charger, solar-charge-controller

in a Camper we usually have many different way to charge the battery (in my case LiFePO4):

- Solar
- Plug
- Engine

It may happen that 2 or more are charging at the same time (for example the Engine and the Solar), the question is: how do they cooperate ? they are connected in paraller which lead to a possible conclusion that they behave as Constant source of current ..

Does anybody have any idea ?

I would like to create my own battery charger by converting the eat of the waste from the gasoline heather (with the support of peltier cells).

Thanks
CC

Comment: We don't know which chargers you have and how they cooperate or don't cooperate.

Answer (score 1):

If your camper is like mine, the charger controller deals with this. It chooses the most appropriate source that’s available and gives priority to it: shore power, then solar, then car battery (alternator).

Further, there’s usually protection to prevent discharging the car battery when the engine isn’t running: it will sense the car battery voltage and only enable sourcing power from it when it sees that the alternator is running (voltage higher than the battery resting charge.) This is a separate little box in my setup.

Comment: The point is that MPPT from VE are able to work in parallel.. this is why I was looking for a way to achieve the same...

Comment: Without knowing the particulars of your controller it's hard to say. The safe assumption is that it uses only one source at a time rather than current-sharing between them.